# How do I check If a JSON string contains a certain symbol

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to find out where a symbol has a minus or a decimal point but can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Here is what I have:

```
  if (strpos($dec, '.')){
        echo "A decimal occured."
      }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if a string contains a specific word in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-to-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

PHP's `strpos` will return the position of the minus or decimal point, if found, or `false` if not found.

```
$spaces = '2,223.00';
$pos = strpos($spaces, '.');

if (false === $pos) {
    echo 'No decimal found';
} else {
    echo 'Decimal found at ' . $pos;
}
```

Note that I used `===` to check the result.

This is explained in detail in the manual at https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Answer (score 0):

```
if(preg_match ( ".", $spaces )){
  echo "A decimal occured."
}

if(preg_match ( "-", $spaces )){
  echo "A minus occured."
}
```

Or comparing bought:

```
if(preg_match ( "/(\.|-)/" , $spaces )){
  echo "Minus or decimal";
}
```

You need to be sure that $spaces is a string

```
strval($spaces);
```

Comment: regular expressions are overkill here

Comment: It's a json encoded string which was converted to a variable. So should it work?